# Dynamic loading of Facebook Comments Plugin throwing JS error in IE 6/7/8

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I am getting the following JS error in IE while trying to dynamically load the
comments plugin.

'null' is null or not an object

dynamic loading of comments plugin does works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari
and Opera, but throwing the above mentioned error in all version of IE (haven't
tested on IE9)

Example page - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3804052/fb-comments-test.html

In the above example page click on "click me to test dynamic loading of
facebook comments plugin" and you can simulate the dynamic loading of comments
plugin, and notice the error in IE6/7/8

Comment: +1 for giving an example link even though you don't have a website.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, hope to see an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

The example link solved my problem. Thanks!

`FB.XFBML.parse();` works like a rockstar!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have those attributes in your  tag?

`xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"`

They are needed for IE to render  properly